# Publish NPM package with Azure DevOps Pipeline task: ArtifactoryNpm@2 to Artifactory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory, npm-publish

I am working on a large project. I need to publish several Angular libraries whose code is in Azure DevOps to JFrog Artifactory.

From previous developers, I found the ***task: ArtifactoryNpm@2*** command in pipeline YAML file, which publishes a package to JFROG using ***command: 'pack and publish'***.
This works if you need to package and publish from the root directory.
In Angular, libraries are created in the subdirectory ***projects/library-name***, which breaks the behavior I want.

My attempts to link to folder or a .tgz file like command:

`'publish $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/projects/library-name'` were also unsuccessful.

I have asked the developers for a detailed description of this task, but did not find any help from them.

Link here https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/issues/209

If you've had a similar experience, let me know how you resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the json file in source code of this task in the following link:

https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/blob/master/tasks/ArtifactoryNpm/Ver2/task.json

There is an argument named `workingFolder`, which path to the folder containing the target `package.json` and `.npmrc` files. Select the folder, not the file e.g. `/packages/mypackage`. You can add `workingFolder` argument in your YAML file.

Comment: Have you checked `workingFolder` argument? Is it working for you?

Comment: How do you incorporate auto incrementation of version numbers into pack and publish?  I don't see anyway of linking a version variable in task: ArtifactoryNpm@2